# Creating a Combination of a Reader and Maybe Monad (Applicative Functor)

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

What I would like to do is make an Applicative Functor out of the Reader monad that does something like this:

```
data MyData = Int Int

get2Sum :: Reader [Int] Int
get2Sum = do
    myData <- ask
    let fst2 = take 2 myData
    case length fst2 of
        2 -> return $ sum fst2
        _ -> return 0

myDataFromApplicative = MyData <$> get2Sum <*> get2Sum

main = print $ runReader myDataFromApplicative [1,2]
```

However, if run something like

```
runReader myDataFromApplicative [1]
```

Instead of giving me `MyData 0 0`

I want it to give me `Error`

I was playing around with creating my own Reader Monad to accomplish this, but couldn't quite figure it out.

What I imagine is something like this (obviously this is just an outline

```
data SuccessReader r a = Interm {runSuccessReader :: r -> SuccessReader a} | Success a | Error
throwError :: SuccessReader ()


get2Sum :: Reader [Int] Int
get2Sum = do
    myData <- ask
    let fst2 = take 2 myData
    case length fst2 of
        2 -> return $ sum fst2
        _ -> throwError

myDataFromApplicative = MyData <$> get2Sum <*> get2Sum

main = do
    print $ runSuccessReader myDataFromApplicative [1,2]
    print $ runSuccessReader myDataFromApplicative [1]
```

which would output

```
Success MyData 3 3
Error
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to write your own monad, as this is exactly the problem that monad transformers and monad stacks solve. Since you want a combination of a `Reader` and `Maybe`, you can use the `ReaderT` transformer with the `Maybe` monad. E.g.

```
get2Sum :: ReaderT [Int] Maybe Int
get2Sum = do
    myData <- ask
    let fst2 = take 2 myData
    case length fst2 of
        2 -> return $ sum fst2
        _ -> lift Nothing
```

The type of `get2Sum` means that we have the outer monad `Reader [Int]` which contains the inner monad `Maybe`. In the implementation of `get2Sum`, `lift` is used to run operations in the inner monad (in this case, simply signalling error with `Nothing`). Now when you run (note the **T** in `runReaderT`)

```
main = do
    print $ runReaderT myDataFromApplicative [1,2]
    print $ runReaderT myDataFromApplicative [1]
```

you get

```
Just (MyData 3 3)
Nothing
```

You could also hide the monad stack inside a custom `newtype`

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Reader

data MyData = MyData Int Int deriving Show

newtype MyMonad a = MyMonad (ReaderT [Int] Maybe a)
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader [Int])

runMyMonad :: MyMonad a -> [Int] -> Maybe a
runMyMonad (MyMonad m) = runReaderT m

myError :: MyMonad a
myError = MyMonad $ lift Nothing

get2Sum :: MyMonad Int
get2Sum = do
    myData <- ask
    let fst2 = take 2 myData
    case length fst2 of
        2 -> return $ sum fst2
        _ -> myError

myDataFromApplicative = MyData <$> get2Sum <*> get2Sum

main = do
    print $ runMyMonad myDataFromApplicative [1,2]
    print $ runMyMonad myDataFromApplicative [1]
```